# Java Fill image into Label

Tags: java, swing, awt, imageicon

I have a fixed size label to display image. How do I have the image resized to fit into the label, filled up. My current code below, is setting the label to the image size, I want it the other way round.

### Code

```
ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(bi);
Label.setIcon(icon);
Dimension imageSize = new Dimension(icon.getIconWidth(), icon.getIconHeight());
Label.setPreferredSize(imageSize);
Label.revalidate();
Label.repaint();
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use Darryl's [Stretch Icon](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2012/03/31/stretch-icon/). The Icon will resize based on the space available to the label.

Answer (score 0):

So if you have a fixed size label, you can simple read image as BufferedImage object and then scale it to size of your label. After that you can create an icon and set it as JLabel's icon. Below code should work:

```
File imageFile = new File("image.jpg");
BufferedImage bufImg = null;

try {
    bufImg = ImageIO.read(imageFile);
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

BufferedImage scaledImg = bufImg.getScaledInstance(Label.width, Label.height, Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);

Label.setIcon(new ImageIcon(scaledImg));
```

Comment: thanks you gave me some idea. But instead of bufferedImage i use image cos it gave me some error

Comment: basically i m not reading image from file, but converted thur a bytearray. Anyway I manage to get the size of the image working thanks.